# How do I obtain Microsoft's C++ compiler and standard library (and just that)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, std

I want to try compiling some C++ code with Microsoft's C++ compiler, and using their standard C++ library. But, I would really rather not install their Visual Studio IDE. I have in the past installed "the whole enchilada", and the compiler naturally worked, but I recall it was really huge.

Now, I know Microsoft has a gratis [Community Edition of its IDE](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/), which includes its compiler, so I should be fine license-wise. Some browsing led me to this download site: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/, but I only seem to be offered variants of Visual Studio, the IDE. If I search around for "Microsoft C++ Compiler", I either find Visual Studio sites, or downloads which seem more relevant scope-wise but are out of date, like [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422). Then there are Windows SDK's, I hope I don't have to get those, or do I? I also remember there are all sorts of ["redistributable" packages you can download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0), and maybe other "build tools" packages - perhaps the compiler is really just a "build tool"?

If I do try the Visual Studio Community Edition installer - I ostensibly get the option to select which components I want to install. But, when I choose *no* components other than the "core C++ desktop features" (which probably means no compiler either), it wants to install 1.9 GB of data... and adding the MSVC v142 build tools bumps me up to 3.86 GB. Yikes!

Bottom line: What should I do so as to install just the MSVC compiler and the standard library (and the minimum possible set of other stuff I don't need alongside them)?

---

Note: [This question](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments/) is closely related to mine, but is not specifically about downloading and installing just the compiler and standard library. Hence one of the answers says: Download MSVS, but just run the compiler. The highest-scored answer ostensibly offers a Visual-Studio-independent download! ... except when you follow the link, you're immediately told the "build tools" are now part of Visual Studio 2017. IIUC anyway.

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-160

Comment: @NathanOliver: That page tells me to first have Visual Studio installed. Also, it tells me about MSBuild, being some other thing than what is offered.

Comment: I'm not seeing that.  It does have *If you only want the command-line toolset, download the Build Tools for Visual Studio* and has a link to said tools.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You're right, I should have read further within that paragraph. ... unfortunately, when I download and install those "build tools", I don't get the C++ compiler. I do get an "msbuild.exe" though. I suppose I might need to enable some more options in the installer dialog.

Comment: When you were looking for the compiler did you run across `cl.exe`?

Comment: @jkb: I looked for `cl.exe` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools` and couldn't find it. Have I missed it somehow?

Comment: I"ve got it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x86` and `...\x64`, and in `...\Host64\x86` and `...\Host64\x64`

Comment: @jkb: I don't have that path... I guess I should checked more options in the installer. Why do they make it so hard to install their compiler, I wonder...

Comment: I think it is not possible to only install several things independent to use VS to compile C++. C++ core/[required components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#components-included-by-this-workload-8) are necessary to be installed, no matter whether you are installing Build Tools or VS IDE.

Comment: @Tianyu: I just don't get why we need all of this stuff. On my Linux machine, GCC 10 is about 50 MB, plus another 50 or so for the C and C++ libraries.

Comment: @einpoklum I've followed this with interest and just got an idea: Try contacting Matt Godbolt. I bet he's solved it for his Compiler Explorer. ... and I hope you write an answer if you figure this out! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio *Build Tools*  is indeed the correct version. I have it installed on our build server.

Yes, it's called "Visual Studio" like the other products in the line, but that doesn't mean it comes with an IDE. It does come with the Visual Studio Installer, so you can select the C++ compiler.

The basic install is `vs_buildtools.exe –quiet –add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools`. This is a C++ "workload" that's not available with the Visual Studio Community, where you'd use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop` instead.

Comment: So, where can I get just `vs_buildtools.exe`, and install it? Or is it only something that you can get for pay?

Comment: @einpoklum: [VS2022 Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2022). No separate license, you'll need to agree to the [VS Community **license**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/vs2022-ga-community/).

Comment: When I try to go there, I get an error saying "MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_OCSP_RESPONSE_FOR_CERT_MISSING".

Comment: @einpoklum I get the same error, using firefox, MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_OCSP_RESPONSE_FOR_CERT_MISSING

Comment: `MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_OCSP_RESPONSE_FOR_CERT_MISSING` is fixed in the [95.0.1](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/95.0.1/releasenotes/) release. Microsoft has upgraded from SHA1 to SHA256, but Firefox was lagging.